# Risks of using a laptop on battery after battery replace warning

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, charging

I am using a Dell Inspiron 5010 (Windows 7 Home Edition), which is 44 months old. About 2 months back, the laptop gave me a battery replacement warning. The LED which turned white when charging, instead started blinking orange. I went to the battery settings and configured the settings to ignore the battery warning. However, recently the battery has stopped getting charged as well and there are frequent warnings from the taskbar about battery issues.

My question is, what are the hazards of continuing to use the laptop on this battery?

Given the age of the laptop, I am considering getting a newer one but cannot afford one right now due to financial constraints (maybe won't be able to buy a new one for another 6 months or so). So I am curious to know how harmful it can be to continue with the laptop in its current state and whether I should spend to get a new battery in the interim.

Comment: What I can think of is just loss of your data caused by unexpected shutdown. If you use your laptop with the AC adapter firmly connected all the time and don't want to see those warnings, you may use the laptop with the battery detached; then you may just forget about the warnings completely as if you use a desktop PC.

Answer (score 1):

The risk is, the battery backup will be less time than before. The Battery may suddenly fail. Nothing beyond this will happen. Its good to have a new battery on hands. If the old battery fails, you can replace with the new one